# Programming the "dynamic" type in C#

Tags: dynamic, boxing, unboxing

When we use dynamic type over object type

weather we can overcome Boxing/UnBoxing overhead ?

```
void Print(dynamic p)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", p.GetType(),p));
}

void Print(object p)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", p.GetType(),p));
}
```

From both the method which one will be efficient and friendly to processor ?

Comment: a) have you measured this yourself? b) Are you pre-optimizing (you should not) or just curious? c) never (very rarely) use the dynamic keyword - there be dragons.

Comment: d) Give a meaningful title.

Comment: Yes, I have verified that but For Boxing/UnBoxing it takes 0/1 Millisecond but for Dynamic, it took for first time arround 39 milliseconds and next consecutive 2 milliseconds.. :(

Comment: Horrible title. Try writing a title in your native language, then translating to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely no difference at all. From Microsoft:

> Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances. However,
>   operations that contain expressions of type dynamic are not resolved
>   or type checked by the compiler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx

From this I infer that dynamic will act as an object until it is used in an expression. This includes parameter passing.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of boxing, it will make no difference.  Take the following code:

```
public class TestClass
{
    static void Test()
    {
        int v = 5;    // Create an unboxed value type variable
        PrintDynamic(v);
    }

    static void PrintDynamic(dynamic p)
    {

    }
}
```

If I decompile the method `Test()` in to IL I get:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Test() cil managed
{
  // Code size       16 (0x10)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] int32 v)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloc.0
  IL_0004:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0009:  call       void ConsoleApplication6.Session::PrintDynamic(object)
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  ret
}
```

You can see that despite the argument to `Test` being declared as `dynamic`, the integer is boxed.

**EDIT**

In response to your question about the discrepancy in timings, consider the following methods:

```
    static void Print(object p)
    {
        string.Format("{0}", p);
    }

    static void PrintDynamic(dynamic p)
    {
        string.Format("{0}", p);
    }
```

The IL for the first looks like this:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Print(object p) cil managed
{
  // Code size       14 (0xe)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "{0}"
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0
  IL_0007:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object)
  IL_000c:  pop
  IL_000d:  ret
} // end of method TestClass::Print
```

For the second:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  PrintDynamic(object p) cil managed
{
  .param [1]
  .custom instance void [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       123 (0x7b)
  .maxstack  8
  .locals init ([0] class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`4<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,class [mscorlib]System.Type,string,object>> ConsoleApplication6.TestClass/'<PrintDynamic>o__SiteContainer0'::'<>p__Site1'
  IL_0006:  brtrue.s   IL_0055
  IL_0008:  ldc.i4     0x100
  IL_000d:  ldstr      "Format"
  IL_0012:  ldnull
  IL_0013:  ldtoken    ConsoleApplication6.TestClass
  IL_0018:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_001d:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_001e:  newarr     [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo
  IL_0023:  stloc.0
  IL_0024:  ldloc.0
  IL_0025:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0026:  ldc.i4.s   33
  IL_0028:  ldnull
  IL_0029:  call       class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags,
                                                                                                                                                                             string)
  IL_002e:  stelem.ref
  IL_002f:  ldloc.0
  IL_0030:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0031:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0032:  ldnull
  IL_0033:  call       class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags,
                                                                                                                                                                             string)
  IL_0038:  stelem.ref
  IL_0039:  ldloc.0
  IL_003a:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_003b:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_003c:  ldnull
  IL_003d:  call       class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags,
                                                                                                                                                                             string)
  IL_0042:  stelem.ref
  IL_0043:  ldloc.0
  IL_0044:  call       class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder::InvokeMember(valuetype [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags,
                                                                                                                                                               string,
                                                                                                                                                               class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [mscorlib]System.Type>,
                                                                                                                                                               class [mscorlib]System.Type,
                                                                                                                                                               class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<class [Microsoft.CSharp]Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo>)
  IL_0049:  call       class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<!0> class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`4<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,class [mscorlib]System.Type,string,object>>::Create(class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder)
  IL_004e:  stsfld     class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`4<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,class [mscorlib]System.Type,string,object>> ConsoleApplication6.TestClass/'<PrintDynamic>o__SiteContainer0'::'<>p__Site1'
  IL_0053:  br.s       IL_0055
  IL_0055:  ldsfld     class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`4<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,class [mscorlib]System.Type,string,object>> ConsoleApplication6.TestClass/'<PrintDynamic>o__SiteContainer0'::'<>p__Site1'
  IL_005a:  ldfld      !0 class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`4<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,class [mscorlib]System.Type,string,object>>::Target
  IL_005f:  ldsfld     class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1<class [mscorlib]System.Action`4<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,class [mscorlib]System.Type,string,object>> ConsoleApplication6.TestClass/'<PrintDynamic>o__SiteContainer0'::'<>p__Site1'
  IL_0064:  ldtoken    [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_0069:  call       class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
  IL_006e:  ldstr      "{0}"
  IL_0073:  ldarg.0
  IL_0074:  callvirt   instance void class [mscorlib]System.Action`4<class [System.Core]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,class [mscorlib]System.Type,string,object>::Invoke(!0,
                                                                                                                                                                                    !1,
                                                                                                                                                                                    !2,
                                                                                                                                                                                    !3)
  IL_0079:  nop
  IL_007a:  ret
} // end of method TestClass::PrintDynamic
```

This goes some way to explain why using `dynamic` initially takes longer.  I suspect there is some caching mechanism going on, meaning that you don't get the performance hit after the first time.

Comment: but I have verified that but For Boxing/UnBoxing it takes 0/1 Millisecond but for Dynamic, it took for first time arround 39 milliseconds and next consecutive 2 milliseconds so Its not same rite ?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves my right:

The first time you use a dynamictype the compiler will generate a callsite that it will use for all consequential read of the variable, hence the slow first hit.

The extra time spent for each read after the initial is to do a lookup for the cached callsite and then performs the unboxing.

Do not hesitate to correct me or add to this answer in the comments!